# conditional by reference of Cells.Find() - VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I want to find "Average":

```
Cells.Find(What:="Average", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
    :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
    False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
```

Let's assume it found in A5. I'm looking for a way to

1. select one cell right (B5)
2. select one cell right-below (B6)
3. if B6 is higher/equal/lower than B5, then the color value of B6
   should be blue/gray/red.
4. The same until reach K5 and K6

PS: All the cells to the right of A5 and A6 are numbers.

Comment: Use `Range().Offset()`

Comment: Please clarify, is cell A5 the only place that can have "Average", or do you want to loop through a column and each time you find "Average" color the cells to Column("K") based on the criteria?

Comment: A5 is just an example. Could be A10, B50, C343243. That's the reason because I wanted to do it through the reference of Cells.Find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did the code for you , but i did without the loop.

Why i did without the loop ? So you can create the loop and get better in vba , if i did all the work for you , it wont help you increase your skills , ok ? Hope you enjoy it my friend!

```
Public Sub PaintValues()

    Dim cl As Range
    Dim clOnRight As Range
    Dim clOnRightBelow As Range

    Set cl = Cells.Find(What:="Average", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt _
        :=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:= _
        False, SearchFormat:=False)

    If cl Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "Average not found in this sheet!", vbExclamation, "Error!"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Get the left cell of Cl (Average)
    Set clOnRight = cl.Offset(0, 1)
    Set clOnRightBelow = cl.Offset(1, 1)

    If clOnRightBelow > clOnRight Then
        clOnRightBelow.Interior.Color = vbBlue
    ElseIf clOnRightBelow = clOnRight Then
        clOnRightBelow.Interior.Color = VBA.RGB(122, 122, 122)
    ElseIf clOnRightBelow < clOnRight Then
        clOnRightBelow.Interior.Color = vbRed
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: It works!, but instead of "Interior" is "Font" (The problem statement is to change the color of the value, not the cell)